# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occures using tess4j without Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tess4j

I use tess4j library for my java app. I followed instructions and copied liblept168.dll and libtesseract302.dll into my project root folder. When I run my app with Eclipse, it works normally. But when I export it as runnable jar file, it gives me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found. But I am sure, that program see this files, because earlier before I added this files it gave me other error, that files can't be found. I also used to copy this dlls to my jar archive, but it didn't help. I am absolutely sure, that I use right jre too. I just can't understand what can be wrong...

```
Tesseract1 api = new Tesseract1();
api.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "(),-+0123456789");
//part of code of getting image
String result = api.doOCR(image);
```

Any ideas?

UPD:
I edited my manifest file as you said and it is:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ jsoup-1.7.3.jar json_simple-1.1.jar Filters.jar ja
>   i_core.jar jna-4.1.0.jar tess4j.jar jai_codec.jar jxl.jar myjsocksj.j 
>   ar jai_imageio.jar
>
> Class-Path: jai_imageio.jar tess4j.jar
>
> Rsrc-Main-Class: com.slando.MainWindow
>
> Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader

Then there were errors about missing dll files and I copied them into jar. And then the same error began to occure.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1
    at com.slando.parser.ImageParser.getNumberFromImage(ImageParser.java:109)
    at com.slando.parser.ImageParser.loadNumberFromImage(ImageParser.java:138)
    at com.slando.parser.ImageParser.loadNumberFromImage(ImageParser.java:144)
    at com.slando.parser.PageParser.loadPhone(PageParser.java:202)
    at com.slando.parser.PageParser.loadFullInfo(PageParser.java:319)
    at com.slando.HttpThread.run(HttpThread.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

One more:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1396)
at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1156)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.slando.parser.ImageParser.getNumberFromImage(ImageParser.java:109)
at com.slando.parser.ImageParser.loadNumberFromImage(ImageParser.java:138)
at com.slando.parser.ImageParser.loadNumberFromImage(ImageParser.java:144)
at com.slando.parser.PageParser.loadPhone(PageParser.java:202)
at com.slando.parser.PageParser.loadFullInfo(PageParser.java:319)
at com.slando.HttpThread.run(HttpThread.java:58)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Same was the problem with me so I copied the dlls to c:/windows/system32

Comment: Still have the same problem =\. The funniest moment is that it works with Eclipse. Also I am sure, that my program see all files. Because earlier it gave me error, that it can't find files, I added them and there is new error...

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: did yu include the `tessdate` directory and the specified packages along with your package?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has the tess4j jar in its classpath, but your system does not.  To distribute this project, the tess4j jar needs to be in the classpath in your jar manifest.  You can also add the path to this jar to the classpath environment variable in your system settings.

[Someone else had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499084/java-exception-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-net-s)

Comment: I edited post. Pls check it. It didn't help. Maybe any more ideas?